# How can I change the font and color settings for js files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't see where in the fonts and colors settings javascript settings can be changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the IDE options dialog: Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors

In the Display Items list, look for items that start with "Script"

Comment: In vs2012 I can't find anything like this (no script, jscript, javascript) - is there a way to set it in Visual Studio 2012 or if not, is there some kind of an extension for this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10):

VS2012 - Javascript Display Items:

Identifier = "All JS Identifiers"

Keyword = "All JS Keywords, i.e.: var, if, else, this"

String = "all string items"

Comment = "all comments in JS"

Comment: Aaaaaand.... it's gone again.  Anyone find the secret hiding place for javascript formatting in VS 2017?  MS do know that in a web project, most of the code is gonna be javascript, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a completely related topic for this question, but Google redirects me for what I searched, so I guess people may benefit from it being here.

In Visual Studio 2015, if you are working on a `.cshtml` document and if you have `javascript` code inside of it, you need to change `Bracematching(Rectangle)` in `Display Items` list.